# How to resize a SoftwareBitmap?

Tags: c#, uwp

`SoftwareBitmap` is new in UWP. I start with this:

```
var softwareBitmap = EXTERNALVALUE;

// do I even need a writeable bitmap?
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer);

// maybe use BitmapDecoder?
```

I am at a loss. Thank you.

Please note, I don't mean `BitmapImage`; I mean `SoftwareBitmap`.

Comment: That could be any language. Resizing images is not simple. There are some C-language algorithms here: https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/tree/master/src

Comment: I have used ImageMagick to do this in the past.  It was fairly straight forward https://magick.codeplex.com/

Comment: Maybe look at the ScaledHeight and ScaledWidth methods on BitmapTransform?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226254#methods  Not my area, so just a Google-guess.

Comment: Please note, I don't mean `BitmapImage`; I mean `SoftwareBitmap`.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [ScaleEffect](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_ScaleEffect.htm)? I think I have a sample somewhere, though will have to look for it.

Comment: Nope, seems like *ScaleEffect* won't help if you want to resize the image in memory, though if you want to show it resized, it may do the job, hold your image in original size then scale once showing via *CanvasControl*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I take an image file and shrink it to a 100x100 `SoftwareBitmap` and return it as an `ImageSource`.

Since you already have a `SoftwareBitmap` with you, I think your task will be even easier. But hope this gives you an idea.

We will need the `WritableBitmap` only for it's `PixelBuffer` while initializing our newly scaled `SoftwareBitmap` instance. If you can directly create an IBuffer from the byte[] pixel data we have (**pixels** local variable), you can directly provide it to `SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer()` method. No need for a `WritableBitmap` in that case.

Here's the code:

```
private async Task<ImageSource> ProcessImageAsync(StorageFile ImageFile)
    {
        if (ImageFile == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ImageFile cannot be null.");

        //The new size of processed image.
        const int side = 100;

        //Initialize bitmap transformations to be applied to the image.
        var transform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledWidth = side, ScaledHeight = side, InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic };

        //Get image pixels.
        var stream = await ImageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, transform, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

        //Initialize writable bitmap.
        var wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        await wBitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());

        //Create a software bitmap from the writable bitmap's pixel buffer.
        var sBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(wBitmap.PixelBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, side, side, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        //Create software bitmap source.
        var sBitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await sBitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(sBitmap);

        return sBitmapSource;
    }
```

PS. I know this sentence is not supposed to be a part of the answer, but I must say that I have learnt a great deal about XAML/C# and developing Windows Store Apps from your MVA and Channel9 videos! :)

Comment: Is this expensive?

Comment: Not so much, but I later realised that this can be done in a much straight forward way. I asked another question about resizing and grayscale-ing a SoftwareBitmap. Have a look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393902/4062881) answer, it's better than mine, performance wise.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT You can also use the Lumia Imaging SDK - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx. It's awesome!

Answer (score 6):

I've made some tries with *ScaleEffect* and ended with extension method below. In fact the method needs more work on it, but maybe it will help you somehow to move further.

```
public static SoftwareBitmap Resize(this SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, float newWidth, float newHeight)
{
    using (var resourceCreator = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice())
    using (var canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(resourceCreator, softwareBitmap))
    using (var canvasRenderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(resourceCreator, newWidth, newHeight, canvasBitmap.Dpi))
    using (var drawingSession = canvasRenderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
    using (var scaleEffect = new ScaleEffect())
    {
        scaleEffect.Source = canvasBitmap;
        scaleEffect.Scale = new System.Numerics.Vector2(newWidth / softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, newHeight / softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
        drawingSession.DrawImage(scaleEffect);
        drawingSession.Flush();
        return SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(canvasRenderTarget.GetPixelBytes().AsBuffer(), BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a crutch but it might resolve your problem:

```
    private async Task<SoftwareBitmap> ResizeSoftwareBitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, double scaleFactor)
    {
        var resourceCreator = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        var canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(resourceCreator, softwareBitmap);
        var canvasRenderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(resourceCreator, (int)(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth * scaleFactor), (int)(softwareBitmap.PixelHeight * scaleFactor), 96);

        using (var cds = canvasRenderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            cds.DrawImage(canvasBitmap, canvasRenderTarget.Bounds);
        }

        var pixelBytes = canvasRenderTarget.GetPixelBytes();

        var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth * scaleFactor), (int)(softwareBitmap.PixelHeight * scaleFactor));
        using (var stream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(pixelBytes, 0, pixelBytes.Length);
        }

        var scaledSoftwareBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth * scaleFactor), (int)(softwareBitmap.PixelHeight * scaleFactor));
        scaledSoftwareBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer);

        return scaledSoftwareBitmap;
    }
```

You have to get Win2D package from nuget.