# Image hashing in UWP/C#, the image repeats horizontally after scaling and graying

Tags: c#, xaml, image-processing, hash, uwp

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html) on image hashing.

So far I have achieved the following:

Code:

```
    private async Task<ImageSource> ProcessImageAsync(StorageFile ImageFile)
    {
        if (ImageFile == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ImageFile cannot be null.");

        //The new size of processed image.
        const int side = 300; //300 is for clarity. Should be 8 or 16 px.

        //Initialize bitmap transformations to be applied to the image.
        var transform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledWidth = side, ScaledHeight = side, InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic };

        //Get image pixels.
        var stream = await ImageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, transform, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

        //Initialize writable bitmap.
        var wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        await wBitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());

        //Make it gray
        var grayBitmapBuffer = await ConvertToGrayAsync(wBitmap);

        //Create a software bitmap from the writable bitmap's pixel buffer.
        var sBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(wBitmap.PixelBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, side, side, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        //Create software bitmap source.
        var sBitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await sBitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(sBitmap);

        return sBitmapSource;
    }

    private async Task<IBuffer> ConvertToGrayAsync(WriteableBitmap srcBitmap)
    {
        // Get the source bitmap pixels
        byte[] srcPixels = new byte[4 * srcBitmap.PixelWidth * srcBitmap.PixelHeight];

        using (Stream pixelStream = srcBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await pixelStream.ReadAsync(srcPixels, 0, srcPixels.Length);
        }

        // Create a destination bitmap and pixels array
        WriteableBitmap dstBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(srcBitmap.PixelWidth, srcBitmap.PixelHeight);
        byte[] dstPixels = new byte[4 * dstBitmap.PixelWidth * dstBitmap.PixelHeight];


        for (int i = 0; i < srcPixels.Length; i += 4)
        {
            double b = (double)srcPixels[i] / 255.0;
            double g = (double)srcPixels[i + 1] / 255.0;
            double r = (double)srcPixels[i + 2] / 255.0;

            byte a = srcPixels[i + 3];

            double e = (0.21 * r + 0.71 * g + 0.07 * b) * 255;
            byte f = Convert.ToByte(e);

            dstPixels[i] = f;
            dstPixels[i + 1] = f;
            dstPixels[i + 2] = f;
            dstPixels[i + 3] = a;

        }

        // Move the pixels into the destination bitmap
        using (Stream pixelStream = dstBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await pixelStream.WriteAsync(dstPixels, 0, dstPixels.Length);
        }
        dstBitmap.Invalidate();

        // Display the new bitmap
        return dstBitmap.PixelBuffer;
    }
```

This is the original image which user selects:
[image: Original image]

And this is the output produced by my code:
[image: Processed image]

It is getting scaled and grayed all-right. But I don't understand why is the image repeating horizontally??

Here is the XAML code that renders the image:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="None" />
```

And the C# code that sets the image source:

```
StorageFile userPickedFile = ...; //code ignored.
myImage.Source = await ProcessImageAsync(userPickedFile);
```

What am I doing wrong? Something looks fishy about the processed image.. I am lost from here... How should I move ahead with Hashing? Any help?

Comment: you are copying the image into an image with a different horizontal dimension.  the affect you are seeing is not a repeat but rather more than one horizontal line of the image copied to a single line line in your result.  Validate the dimensions and horizontal stride of the inbound and destination images.

Comment: @WilliamJones Thank-you for your explanation. But my destination image dimensions are predefined.

Comment: I would try using the Lumia imaging sdk and apply a gray scale filter.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx

Comment: @KenTucker I guess `Lumia Imaging SDK` is what I should have used long ago.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ConvertToGrayAsync` method should simply return the converted WriteableBitmap. The pixel conversion code inside the loop could also be simplified, and the method does not need to operate on a source and destination buffer. It could as well manipulate the pixel values in place.

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> ConvertToGrayAsync(WriteableBitmap srcBitmap)
{
    var pixels = srcBitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
    {
        var b = pixels[i];
        var g = pixels[i + 1];
        var r = pixels[i + 2];
        var f = (byte)(0.21 * r + 0.71 * g + 0.07 * b);
        pixels[i] = f;
        pixels[i + 1] = f;
        pixels[i + 2] = f;
    }

    var dstBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(srcBitmap.PixelWidth, srcBitmap.PixelHeight);

    using (var pixelStream = dstBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    }

    return dstBitmap;
}
```

The following method loads a WriteableBitmap with a predefined size:

```
private static async Task<WriteableBitmap> LoadWriteableBitmapAsync(
    StorageFile file, int width, int height)
{
    using (var fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    using (var memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
        var transform = new BitmapTransform
        {
            ScaledWidth = (uint)width,
            ScaledHeight = (uint)height,
            InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic
        };
        var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            transform,
            ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

        using (var pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Your `ProcessImageAsync` method would now look like this:

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> ProcessImageAsync(
    StorageFile file, int width, int height)
{
    return await ConvertToGrayAsync(
        await LoadWriteableBitmapAsync(file, width, height));
}
```

Comment: Wonderful.. Thank you for your answer. 

However, the scaling is an issue now. I pass say `w`, `h` as parameters to the constructor of `WriteableBitmap`, but the width always remains the original, and height remains the smaller value of `w` or `h`.

Comment: Also if I don't call `ConvertToGrayAsync()` and directly return the bitmap, the size doesn't change at all.

Comment: Please see my edit for another ProcessImageAsync method, which woud also resize the bitmap.