# SoftwareBitmap compared to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmapimage

So I'm creating a UWP app which includes an `InkCanvas`, as such, I want to store the contents as a variable so that I can show a preview of the canvas in the menu.

My question is, what is the best `bitmap` to use, as there appear to be a number of options.

The `SoftwareBitmap` is included in `Windows.Graphics.Imaging`, whereas the `BitmapImage` is part of `Windows.UI.XAML.Media.Imaging`, both of which are available in a UWP app.

Can the UWP `Image` class for displaying images use either of these formats?

**Which is most appropriate** in my case?

Comment: "Can the UWP Image class for displaying images use either of these formats". You can easily find that out. Just check if the bitmap class is derived from `ImageSource`, which is the type of the Image control's `Source` property. Anything that is an ImageSource can be assigned to that property. Which is the most appropriate depends on the way you create or manipulate a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having done much experimenting, it seems for use with the `Image` control from `Windows.UI.XAML.Controls`, a `SoftwareBitmap` works fairly well.

A `SoftwareBitmapSource` can be assigned to the `Image.Source`, provided the `SoftwareBitmap` has `BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8` and `BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied` (or `BitmapAlphaMode.None`). From the Remarks section on the [SoftwareBitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.softwarebitmapsource#remarks) page:

> A SoftwareBitmap displayed in a XAML app must be in BGRA pixel format with pre-multiplied alpha values

All works nicely, now to work on scaling the bitmap down as the difference in size between the `InkCanvas` and `Image` make the thumbnail/preview look poor.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393902/1136211) for an example of how to resize a WriteableBitmap.